# Computer restarting without warning

Tags: bsod, reboot

Recently, my computer has been restarting without warning. This started a few months ago after I got a BSOD when I was watching something with MPC. I got other BSODs later when I was watching videos (using MPC, and also once on Youtube), but they've stopped (now, the computer only restarts). It also restarts when I play certain video games. How do I found out what's causing this, and stop it?
Forgot to add, I know it isn't overheating.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qeiruif1vby40b8/Minidump.zip?dl=0

Also, I think this is related. My DVD drive has been making strange sounds constantly, like it's trying to read a DVD, but there's nothing in there.

Comment: Right click in your computer and choose properties. Then click "advanced system settings" in your left and click on the 3rd "settings" button in the Start up and recovery field. Uncheck the "automatically restart" option so you can tell us what BSOD is about!

Comment: I unchecked it after the first BSOD.

Comment: If you're getting a BSOD you should be presented with a blue screen showing a **STOP** or **Bugcheck** code. Please post that and also tell us what OS you're running.

Comment: I'm on Windows 7. The bug check code says 0x1000007e

Comment: copy the folder **C:\Windows\minidump** to your desktop, zip the folder and upload the zip (OneDrive, Dropbox) and post a link here.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qeiruif1vby40b8/Minidump.zip?dl=0

Comment: the last dump is over 1 month old and is likely caused by the AMD driver. If you see kernel error 41, check this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504/

Comment: Yes, I knew about the driver, so I reinstalled them and the BSODs stopped. Can random restarts also be caused by bad drivers?

Comment: check the steps from the KB article.

Comment: It just restarted again. It still doesn't give a bug check code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in the event viewer and see if there are any critical errors related to shutdowns. It should provide a description.

Start + R -> eventvwr.msc

Going by your comment response, the Kernel-Power 41 (63) could suggest overheating or a RAM problem. Try running a MemTest to find results or re-seat the RAM. Alternatively, I'd suggest the power supply is now incapable of doing the job in hand and is not providing either enough electricity, or the power supply is gone in it. I'd suggest, after finding this information, we move this over to the [Electronics](http://electronics.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: It says Kernel-Power 41 (63).

Comment: Would this apply to you? http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1820592/kernel-power-error-event-task-catergory.html

Comment: No, I've never overclocked my computer and some of the values are different.

Comment: Hmm I'm on the phone so I'll carry on looking

Comment: This is not an answer ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Forgot to finish off, edited.

Comment: How do I check to see if the power supply provides enough electricity?

Comment: @hulud the easiest way is to try a different, more powerful power supply.

Comment: How long should I leave the memtest running?

Comment: It should just complete by itself

Comment: Okay. If no problems are found with the RAM, that would leave only the power supply, correct? I've had this computer for almost 3 years now. How long do power supplies usually last?

Comment: I did the memtest for the first stick, but it finished while I was sleeping. Will I have to test it again to see if there were any problems?

Comment: No, it should give a problem summary

Comment: Wait, I switched the RAM sticks so I could start the second test, but I had to press the power button multiple times to get the computer to start (the fans would start spinning, stop, and the computer would shut down). That points to the power supply, right?

Comment: I'd suggest that would, almost 100%, but you shouldn't swap them between tests. It will tell you which slot has the faulty RAM stick, just re-seat them.

Comment: Alright. I'll do one more test just to be sure and I'll start looking into other power supplies. Will any power supply be compatible with my motherboard?

Comment: I've installed a new PSU, everything seems fine for now. I'll try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Forgot to add, the wattage on my new PSU (550) is less than the one listed on my old one (700), but will that be a problem? Since the old one was failing, that would mean the wattage was actually much lower, right?

Comment: It should be fine, if its working... at least it shouldn't overheat :-)

Comment: I've tried reproducing the restarts, and they're gone now. My CPU has gotten pretty close to overheating once, if that's what you were talking about, so I'll see about getting a more powerful PSU later.